# apply CSS to google maps iframe

Tags: css, google-maps

I'm trying to apply css to google maps iframe in order to get rid of that ugly banner:
[image]

But I don't find a way to link my stylesheet to that iframe.. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope there is no way to style an external source, which you have no access to it. The only way to do this is to use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed google map iframe instead of this code it helps you to design your code as you wish and also do not add border strip. 
If it is not working then try to create the new location on google map with same address and then add that iframe it exactly work as you want.

another way to add this jquery code in your file.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.name-of-class').css('display','none');
    // find the name of the class using inspect element and then replace
    // it with the class name it will work 100%
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a solution to hide the top banner from a Google My Maps. Found a solution here: http://www.howtoonlinetips.com/hide-google-map-top-bar-embedded-header/

It worked well for my needs. Just wrapped the iframe with a div and hide the top part.

```
<div style="height:400px; width:100%; display:inline-block; overflow:hidden;"> 
   <iframe class="custom-google-map" style="position:relative; top:-50px; border:none;" src="http://source-fo-the-map.com" width="What Ever Width" height="445" />
</div>
```